# How to connect postgresql database server deployed on azure cloud to an app service on azure which uses prisma db?

Tags: postgresql, azure, next.js, prisma

I have tried the method mentioned in the docs of prisma i.e

```
postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE
```

but whenever I run this command

```
npx prisma db push
```

which is the command to push your prisma schema to your database server, I get this error

> Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at calendso-postgres:5432

For debugging I have tried connecting to the database using the psql command i.e

```
psql "host=<host> port=<port> dbname={your_database} user=<username> password={your_password} sslmode=require"
```

from the terminal of my local machine and this works just fine.

Any suggestions / solutions on what am I doing wrong or what should I do will be appreciable .

Apologies for my English, some important points:

- database is running on an Azure server
- the app service to which I want to connect the database is based on nextjs framework
- `https://github.com/calendso/calendso` this is the open source repo of the app I have deployed on Azure

Comment: Just for clarification, you can't connect when running ```npx prisma db push``` locally, correct? Firstly, could you also mention what version of Prisma you're using? Secondly, check in Azure if connecting to the database requires SSL. Finally, A common reason is if the default timeouts might be too low if the database server is far away. Could you explicitly pass the timeout values as arguments in the connection URL by appending ```?connect_timeout=100&pool_timeout=100&socket_timeout=100``` at the end of the connection string and then try again?

Comment: * Yes! I can't connect to the database when the running the above mentioned command.
* I am using ```"@prisma/client": "^2.23.0"``` .
* Yes, it requires ssl.
I will implement the solution that you have mentioned and will revert back.
@TasinIshmam

Comment: I passed the timeout values explicitly, still the error remains the same as mentioned in the original post. @TasinIshmam

Comment: I have used this connection string ```postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:5432/<dbname>?connect_timeout=100&pool_timeout=100&socket_timeout=100&sslmode=require``` and still the same error.@TasinIshmam

Comment: Hi @SourabhSingh did you ever resolve this?